# How put tikzpictures in rows?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

Currently I have 8 different pictures and I want to put them in 2 rows of 4 (so 4 pictures per line). These tikzpicture also have arrow head which I would like to get rid off.

If someone could type up the code to do that, I would really appreciate it!

```
   \begin{document}
   \pagestyle{plain}
   \thispagestyle{fancy} 
   \begin{enumerate}
    \item The number of nonisomorphic simple graphs with 2 vertices is 2
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2]
    \tikzstyle{every node}+=[inner sep=0pt]
    \draw [black] (12.9,-27.4) circle (3);
    \draw [black] (27.2,-27.4) circle (3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}

    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2]
    \tikzstyle{every node}+=[inner sep=0pt]
    \draw [black] (12.7,-27.4) circle (3);
    \draw [black] (27.2,-27.4) circle (3);
    \draw [black] (15.7,-27.4) -- (24.2,-27.4);
    \fill [black] (24.2,-27.4) -- (23.4,-26.9) -- (23.4,-27.9);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
    \item The number of nonisomorphic simple graphs with 3 vertices is 8
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2]
    \tikzstyle{every node}+=[inner sep=0pt]
    \draw [black] (38.4,-10) circle (3);
    \draw [black] (30,-23.4) circle (3);
    \draw [black] (46.2,-23.4) circle (3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2]
    \tikzstyle{every node}+=[inner sep=0pt]
    \draw [black] (37.3,-9.3) circle (3);
    \draw [black] (30,-23.4) circle (3);
    \draw [black] (46.4,-22.7) circle (3);
    \draw [black] (35.92,-11.96) -- (31.38,-20.74);
    \fill [black] (31.38,-20.74) -- (32.19,-20.26) -- (31.3,-19.8);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2]
    \tikzstyle{every node}+=[inner sep=0pt]
    \draw [black] (37.3,-9.3) circle (3);
    \draw [black] (30,-23.4) circle (3);
    \draw [black] (46.4,-22.7) circle (3);
    \draw [black] (33,-23.27) -- (43.4,-22.83);
    \fill [black] (43.4,-22.83) -- (42.58,-22.36) -- (42.62,-23.36);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2]
    \tikzstyle{every node}+=[inner sep=0pt]
    \draw [black] (37.3,-9.3) circle (3);
    \draw [black] (30,-23.4) circle (3);
    \draw [black] (46.4,-22.7) circle (3);
    \draw [black] (39.9,-11.2) -- (44.92,-20.09);
    \fill [black] (44.92,-20.09) -- (44.97,-19.15) -- (44.09,-19.64);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2]
    \tikzstyle{every node}+=[inner sep=0pt]
    \draw [black] (37.3,-9.3) circle (3);
    \draw [black] (30,-23.4) circle (3);
    \draw [black] (46.4,-22.7) circle (3);
    \draw [black] (39.9,-11.2) -- (44.92,-20.09);
    \fill [black] (44.92,-20.09) -- (44.97,-19.15) -- (44.09,-19.64);
    \draw [black] (35.92,-11.96) -- (31.38,-20.74);
    \fill [black] (31.38,-20.74) -- (32.19,-20.26) -- (31.3,-19.8);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2]
    \tikzstyle{every node}+=[inner sep=0pt]
    \draw [black] (37.3,-9.3) circle (3);
    \draw [black] (30,-23.4) circle (3);
    \draw [black] (46.4,-22.7) circle (3);
    \draw [black] (33,-23.27) -- (43.4,-22.83);
    \fill [black] (43.4,-22.83) -- (42.58,-22.36) -- (42.62,-23.36);
    \draw [black] (31.38,-20.74) -- (35.92,-11.96);
    \fill [black] (35.92,-11.96) -- (35.11,-12.44) -- (36,-12.9);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2]
    \tikzstyle{every node}+=[inner sep=0pt]
    \draw [black] (37.3,-9.3) circle (3);
    \draw [black] (30,-23.4) circle (3);
    \draw [black] (46.4,-22.7) circle (3);
    \draw [black] (43.4,-22.83) -- (33,-23.27);
    \fill [black] (33,-23.27) -- (33.82,-23.74) -- (33.78,-22.74);
    \draw [black] (44.71,-20.22) -- (38.99,-11.78);
    \fill [black] (38.99,-11.78) -- (39.02,-12.72) -- (39.85,-12.16);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2]
    \tikzstyle{every node}+=[inner sep=0pt]
    \draw [black] (37.5,-7.8) circle (3);
    \draw [black] (30,-23.4) circle (3);
    \draw [black] (46.4,-22.7) circle (3);
    \draw [black] (36.2,-10.5) -- (31.3,-20.7);
    \fill [black] (31.3,-20.7) -- (32.1,-20.19) -- (31.2,-19.76);
    \draw [black] (33.2,-22.7) -- (43.4,-22.7);
    \fill [black] (43.4,-22.7) -- (42.6,-22.2) -- (42.6,-23.2);
    \draw [black] (44.6,-20.3) -- (38.98,-10.41);
    \fill [black] (38.98,-10.41) -- (38.94,-11.35) -- (39.81,-10.86);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

These are my pictures:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please give us a complete example we can compile. But use `\begin{minipage}{<width>}\centering ...\end{minipage}` rather than the `center` environment. Or use a single `center` environment. Note that `\tikzstyle` is deprecated.

Comment: Okay I've changed the code. Is it satisfactory now? @cfr

Comment: Thanks. Though you probably need a document class and to load `tikz`, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

[image: 4-by-4]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{%
  every node/.append style={inner sep=0pt}
}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.1]
    \draw [black] (38.4,-10) circle (3);
    \draw [black] (30,-23.4) circle (3);
    \draw [black] (46.2,-23.4) circle (3);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.1]
    \draw [black] (37.3,-9.3) circle (3);
    \draw [black] (30,-23.4) circle (3);
    \draw [black] (46.4,-22.7) circle (3);
    \draw [black] (35.92,-11.96) -- (31.38,-20.74);
    \fill [black] (31.38,-20.74) -- (32.19,-20.26) -- (31.3,-19.8);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.1]
    \draw [black] (37.3,-9.3) circle (3);
    \draw [black] (30,-23.4) circle (3);
    \draw [black] (46.4,-22.7) circle (3);
    \draw [black] (33,-23.27) -- (43.4,-22.83);
    \fill [black] (43.4,-22.83) -- (42.58,-22.36) -- (42.62,-23.36);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.1]
    \draw [black] (37.3,-9.3) circle (3);
    \draw [black] (30,-23.4) circle (3);
    \draw [black] (46.4,-22.7) circle (3);
    \draw [black] (39.9,-11.2) -- (44.92,-20.09);
    \fill [black] (44.92,-20.09) -- (44.97,-19.15) -- (44.09,-19.64);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.1]
    \draw [black] (37.3,-9.3) circle (3);
    \draw [black] (30,-23.4) circle (3);
    \draw [black] (46.4,-22.7) circle (3);
    \draw [black] (39.9,-11.2) -- (44.92,-20.09);
    \fill [black] (44.92,-20.09) -- (44.97,-19.15) -- (44.09,-19.64);
    \draw [black] (35.92,-11.96) -- (31.38,-20.74);
    \fill [black] (31.38,-20.74) -- (32.19,-20.26) -- (31.3,-19.8);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.1]
    \draw [black] (37.3,-9.3) circle (3);
    \draw [black] (30,-23.4) circle (3);
    \draw [black] (46.4,-22.7) circle (3);
    \draw [black] (33,-23.27) -- (43.4,-22.83);
    \fill [black] (43.4,-22.83) -- (42.58,-22.36) -- (42.62,-23.36);
    \draw [black] (31.38,-20.74) -- (35.92,-11.96);
    \fill [black] (35.92,-11.96) -- (35.11,-12.44) -- (36,-12.9);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.1]
    \draw [black] (37.3,-9.3) circle (3);
    \draw [black] (30,-23.4) circle (3);
    \draw [black] (46.4,-22.7) circle (3);
    \draw [black] (43.4,-22.83) -- (33,-23.27);
    \fill [black] (33,-23.27) -- (33.82,-23.74) -- (33.78,-22.74);
    \draw [black] (44.71,-20.22) -- (38.99,-11.78);
    \fill [black] (38.99,-11.78) -- (39.02,-12.72) -- (39.85,-12.16);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.1]
    \draw [black] (37.5,-7.8) circle (3);
    \draw [black] (30,-23.4) circle (3);
    \draw [black] (46.4,-22.7) circle (3);
    \draw [black] (36.2,-10.5) -- (31.3,-20.7);
    \fill [black] (31.3,-20.7) -- (32.1,-20.19) -- (31.2,-19.76);
    \draw [black] (33.2,-22.7) -- (43.4,-22.7);
    \fill [black] (43.4,-22.7) -- (42.6,-22.2) -- (42.6,-23.2);
    \draw [black] (44.6,-20.3) -- (38.98,-10.41);
    \fill [black] (38.98,-10.41) -- (38.94,-11.35) -- (39.81,-10.86);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```